# Fatal Error EDebug.pas(3094): Could not create output file P:\Trails\Gui\SD\obj\EDebug.dcu

Tags: delphi

I am trying to build an old Delphi 7 project.

I am using an old VM where I am supposed to open the project in Delphi and build it. When I do that I get the error message you see in the title.

Background:
I got the vm from my colleague (and he got it from an old colleague) that has left the company.
The issue seems to be the fact that VM has shared folders that I am missing on my host. The `P:\` drive is pointing to nowhere on the guest vm.

What I need is to tell Delphi that `EDebug.dcu` should not go to `P:\Trails\Gui\SD\obj\EDebug.dcu` but instead it should go somewhere under `c:\` drive. 
Any way to do that?

Comment: Open the project settings and change there the folder for DCU output (_"Unit output directory"_).

Comment: This worked!! Thank you, the project is building now!